# Retrofit returns error 401, NullPointerException for android 4.4.2

Tags: android, retrofit

my code

```
 private void autenticar(TipoLogin tipoLogin, Cidadao cidadao) throws Throwable {
    // Captura o tipo de opção de login
    final Integer opcao = tipoLogin.getCodigo();

    this.apiAcessoDAO = FabricaDAO.criarApiAcessoDAO(this.context);


    Prefeitura prefeitura = null;
    PrefeituraDAO prefeituraDAO = null;

    try {
        prefeituraDAO = FabricaDAO.criarPrefeituraDAO(context);
        prefeitura = prefeituraDAO.carregar();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").create();

    // Crio um restadapter
    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setServer(prefeitura.getUrlBase())
            .setErrorHandler(new ExceptionNetwork(this.context))
            .setClient(new OkClient())
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
            .build();

    CidadaoAPI cidadaoAPI = restAdapter.create(CidadaoAPI.class);

    ApiAcesso apiAcesso = null;

    // opção selecionada pelo usuário (tipo login)
    switch (opcao)
    {
        case 1:
            apiAcesso = cidadaoAPI.autenticar(cidadao.getSenhaPortal(), tipoLogin.getUrl(), cidadao.getFoneCelular1());
            break;
        case 2:
            apiAcesso = cidadaoAPI.autenticar(cidadao.getSenhaPortal(), tipoLogin.getUrl(), cidadao.getEmail());
            break;
        case 3:
            apiAcesso = cidadaoAPI.autenticar(cidadao.getSenhaPortal(), tipoLogin.getUrl(), cidadao.getCpf());
            break;
        case 4:
            apiAcesso = cidadaoAPI.autenticar(cidadao.getSenhaPortal(), tipoLogin.getUrl(), cidadao.getNumeroCartaoSus());
            break;
        case 5:
            apiAcesso = cidadaoAPI.autenticar(cidadao.getSenhaPortal(), tipoLogin.getUrl(), cidadao.getRegistroCidadao());
            break;
    }

    // Insere no banco de dados
    try {
        this.apiAcessoDAO.deletar();
        this.apiAcessoDAO.inserir(apiAcesso);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

my error handle

```
public class ExceptionNetwork implements ErrorHandler {

private Context context;

public ExceptionNetwork(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

/**
 * Return a custom exception to be thrown for a {@link retrofit.RetrofitError}. It is recommended that you
 * pass the supplied error as the cause to any new exceptions.
 * <p/>
 * If the return exception is checked it must be declared to be thrown on the interface method.
 * <p/>
 * Example usage:
 * <pre>
 * class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
 *   &#64;Override public Throwable handleError(RetrofitError cause) {
 *     Response r = cause.getResponse();
 *     if (r != null &amp;&amp; r.getStatus() == 401) {
 *       return new UnauthorizedException(cause);
 *     }
 *     return cause;
 *   }
 * }
 * </pre>
 *
 * @param cause the original {@link retrofit.RetrofitError} exception
 * @return Throwable an exception which will be thrown from a synchronous interface method or
 * passed to an asynchronous error callback. Must not be {@code null}.
 */
@Override
public Throwable handleError(RetrofitError cause) {

    Response response = cause.getResponse();

    if(response.getStatus() == 401) {
        try {
            return new Exception(this.context.getString(R.string.internete_nao_autorizado));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else
    if(response != null && response.getStatus() == 404) {
        try {
            return new Exception(this.context.getString(R.string.internete_nao_encontrado));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else
    if(response != null && response.getStatus() == 307)
    {
        try
        {
            return new Exception(this.context.getString(R.string.internete_link_redirecionado));
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else
    if(response == null)
    {
        try {
            return new Exception(this.context.getString(R.string.internete_link_offiline));
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return new Exception(this.context.getString(R.string.internete_link_offiline));
}
```

}

error

```
05-20 13:27:21.968    1243-1243/br.com.appsap.app W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
05-20 13:27:21.968    1243-1243/br.com.appsap.app W/System.err﹕ at br.com.appsap.app.exeption.ExceptionNetwork.handleError(ExceptionNetwork.java:52)
05-20 13:27:21.968    1243-1243/br.com.appsap.app W/System.err﹕ at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:286)
05-20 13:27:21.968    1243-1243/br.com.appsap.app W/System.err﹕ at $Proxy2.autenticar(Native Method)
05-20 13:27:21.968    1243-1243/br.com.appsap.app W/System.err﹕ at br.com.appsap.app.controller.implementacao.CidadaoControllerImplementacao.autenticar(CidadaoControllerImplementacao.java:176)
05-20 13:27:21.968    1243-1243/br.com.appsap.app W/System.err﹕ at br.com.appsap.app.controller.implementacao.CidadaoControllerImplementacao.login(CidadaoControllerImplementacao.java:129)
05-20 13:27:21.968    1243-1243/br.com.appsap.app W/System.err﹕ at br.com.appsap.app.view.LoginActivity$PlaceholderFragment.onClick(LoginActivity.java:320)
05-20 13:27:21.968    1243-1243/br.com.appsap.app W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
05-20 13:27:21.968    1243-1243/br.com.appsap.app W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
05-20 13:27:21.968    1243-1243/br.com.appsap.app W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-20 13:27:21.968    1243-1243/br.com.appsap.app W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-20 13:27:21.968    1243-1243/br.com.appsap.app W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-20 13:27:21.968    1243-1243/br.com.appsap.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-20 13:27:21.968    1243-1243/br.com.appsap.app W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 13:27:21.968    1243-1243/br.com.appsap.app W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-20 13:27:21.968    1243-1243/br.com.appsap.app W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-20 13:27:21.968    1243-1243/br.com.appsap.app W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-20 13:27:21.968    1243-1243/br.com.appsap.app W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: If you are going to check for null pointer in the if statements, then you should be sure that you are checking for a null pointer on the first if condition within handle error as well.  The line number printed out doesn't match up with that line that I can tell, but if you are not getting a response back, this could be the culprit.

Comment: I wonder why the null pointer is coming. When I force the error 401.

Comment: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/382 retrofitError getResponse returning null for 401

Answer (score 1):

TO solve your problem you need to include ok-http-library. But be aware of compatability issues.Here is my working setup:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.7.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
```

Comment: I put the page to request a login and password authorization and solved the problem, thanks.